# xlsxwriter- Writing a list to a column

Tags: python

Anyone have an idea how to write to a column. I am parsing data from one excel sheet based on what is in a specific column and turning it to a list to easily skip the first two columns.

After I'm trying to insert that list into a new sheet and have each element in the list be inserted in a new column within the same row.

My code only adds one element ("RDU1-RX04") from parsed into A1.

Can anyone help in determining what I am doing wrong? I couldn't find enough information to try to piece this together. Am I taking an approach that even makes sense?

parsed = ['RDU1-TX01', 'RDU1-TX01', 'RDU1-TX01', 'RDU1-RX01', 'RDU1-RX01', 'RDU1-RX01', 'RDU1-RX02', 'RDU1-RX02', 'RDU1-RX02', 'RDU1-RX03', 'RDU1-RX03', 'RDU1-RX03', 'RDU1-RX04', 'RDU1-RX04', 'RDU1-RX04']

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

PRWB = xlrd.open_workbook('prsheet.xlsx')
PRSHEET= PRWB.sheet_by_index(0)
PRSHEET.cell_value(0, 0)
X = []

for i in range(PRSHEET.nrows):
    a = PRSHEET.cell_value(i, 2)
    X.append(a)
    parsed= map(str, X)[2:]

print (parsed)

IPAMWB = xlsxwriter.Workbook('pripam.xlsx')
IPAMSHEET= IPAMWB.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')

for t in parsed:
    IPAMSHEET.write(0, 0, t)

IPAMWB.close()
```

[The output file I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7KSJ.png)
[The output desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEqm7.png)

Comment: `IPAMSHEET.write(0, 0, t)` has hard-coded cell values? So you just keep overwriting the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is wondering the solution was actually to create a counter. What was happening was it was replacing my elements over and over until it reached the last one in that same column. I created a count starting from the 6th column and increased after every element iteration.

```
import xlrd
import xlsxwriter

PRWB = xlrd.open_workbook('prsheet.xlsx')
PRSHEET= PRWB.sheet_by_index(0)
PRSHEET.cell_value(0, 0)
X = []

for i in range(PRSHEET.nrows):
    a = PRSHEET.cell_value(i, 2)
    X.append(a)
    parsed= map(str, X)[2:]

print (parsed)

IPAMWB = xlsxwriter.Workbook('pripam.xlsx')
IPAMSHEET= IPAMWB.add_worksheet('Sheet 1')

count=5

for t in parsed:
    IPAMSHEET.write(count, 3, t)
    count+=1

IPAMWB.close()
```

Comment: Note, that there is also a [write_column()](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#worksheet-write-column) Worksheet method specifically for writing lists in a column format.

Answer (score 1):

Query - I had to import employees names from an outside Excel sheet and write those in a column in my current sheet. Working code is below.

```
# Importing packages
import xlsxwriter
import pandas as pd

#Creating workbook and worksheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook("newsheet.xlsx")
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet("namesheet")

# importing names from outside sheet and writing those in a column (Column 0) in current sheet

df = pd.read_excel('mysheet.xlsx',sheet_name='sheet1')
emp_list = df['Name'].to_list()  #Fetching names and stored in a list

for row_count in range (0,len(emp_list)):
    worksheet.write(row_count,0,emp_list[row_count])

workbook.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(parsed)

writer = pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx')
df1.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',header=False)
```